# How can I split data present in an array into another array.?

Tags: c#

Basically, I am trying to split an array and want to pass its value into another array.
But, I am not able to do it.It is givin an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type String[] to string"

```
StreamReader EmployeeFile = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\FoodDeliverySystem\Employee_details.txt");
String ReadEmployeeData = EmployeeFile.ReadToEnd();
String[] ReadEmployeeDataByLine = ReadEmployeeData.Split(';');
for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
{
     for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("test");
          String[,] ReadEmployeeDataByLineByCategorie = new string[k, l];
          ReadEmployeeDataByLineByCategorie[k,l] = ReadEmployeeDataByLine[l].Split(',');
     }
}
```

Comment: Or tell the alternate easy way to do this.

Comment: The error is clear - can you explain what you intend to do? Always watch your types - you can't assign a `string[]` to a `string`.

Comment: It's pretty clear what I intend to do. I know what the error says that's why I am looking fo the answer here.

Comment: "want to pass its value into another array" has no reasonable meaning. Please try to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't be sure of how many of those values you're gonna have in each category of yours, you should use [jagged arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays)

That should do:

```
var readEmployeeDataByLine = new StreamReader(@"C:\pathToFile.txt").ReadToEnd().Split(';');
var readEmployeeDataByLineByCategorie = new string[readEmployeeDataByLine.Length][];

for (int i = 0; i < readEmployeeDataByLineByCategorie.Length; i++)
    readEmployeeDataByLineByCategorie[i] = readEmployeeDataByLine[i].Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

`ReadEmployeeDataByLineByCategorie[k,l]` is a `string`
 while `ReadEmployeeDataByLine[l].Split(',')` is a `string[]`

```
string[] ReadEmployeeDataByLine = ReadEmployeeData.Split(';');
for(int i = 0;i< ReadEmployeeDataByLine.Length;i++)
{
    string split = ReadEmployeeDataByLine[l].Split(',');
    for(int j=0; j<split.Length;j++)
         ReadEmployeeDataByLineByCategorie[i,j] = split[j]
}
```